# php pdo fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i'm using fluentpdo - https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo

i'm trying to loop the results from a table into `html` with this code

```
$bxslider = $fpdo->from('bxslider')->select('box_img, box_link, box_title, box_desc');
```

however i'm only getting only 1 result

```
foreach ($bxslider as $bx) {
    $BXSLIDER = "<li>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<em>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<img src='{$bx['box_img']}' alt='{$bx['box_title']}' />";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<a href='{$bx['box_link']}'><i class='fa fa-link icon-hover icon-hover-1'></i></a>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<a href='{$bx['box_img']}' class='fancybox-button' title='{$bx['box_title']}' data-rel='fancybox-button'><i class='fa fa-search icon-hover icon-hover-2'></i></a>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "</em>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<a class='bxslider-block' href='#'>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<strong>{$bx['box_title']}</strong>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<b>{$bx['box_desc']}</b>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "</a>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "</li>";
}

print $BXSLIDER;
```

how do i display all results ?

the problem is not from the fluentpdo class because I have used another class and even the simple `pdo` class from PHP and I still have the same problem on all ...

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting $BXSLIDER with every foreach loop. You need to do something like this:

```
$BXSLIDER = "";
foreach ($bxslider as $bx) {

$BXSLIDER .= "<li>";
                        $BXSLIDER .= "<em>";
                            $BXSLIDER .= "<img src='{$bx['box_img']}' alt='{$bx['box_title']}' />";
                            $BXSLIDER .= "<a href='{$bx['box_link']}'><i class='fa fa-link icon-hover icon-hover-1'></i></a>";
                            $BXSLIDER .= "<a href='{$bx['box_img']}' class='fancybox-button' title='{$bx['box_title']}' data-rel='fancybox-button'><i class='fa fa-search icon-hover icon-hover-2'></i></a>";
                        $BXSLIDER .= "</em>";
                        $BXSLIDER .= "<a class='bxslider-block' href='#'>";
                            $BXSLIDER .= "<strong>{$bx['box_title']}</strong>";
                            $BXSLIDER .= "<b>{$bx['box_desc']}</b>";
                        $BXSLIDER .= "</a>";
                    $BXSLIDER .= "</li>";

}

print $BXSLIDER;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the variable every iteration.

Try:

```
$BXSLIDER = "<ul>";

foreach ($bxslider as $bx) {
    $BXSLIDER .= "<li>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<em>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<img src='{$bx['box_img']}' alt='{$bx['box_title']}' />";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<a href='{$bx['box_link']}'><i class='fa fa-link icon-hover icon-hover-1'></i></a>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<a href='{$bx['box_img']}' class='fancybox-button' title='{$bx['box_title']}' data-rel='fancybox-button'><i class='fa fa-search icon-hover icon-hover-2'></i></a>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "</em>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<a class='bxslider-block' href='#'>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<strong>{$bx['box_title']}</strong>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "<b>{$bx['box_desc']}</b>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "</a>";
    $BXSLIDER .= "</li>";
}
$BXSLIDER .= "</ul>";

print $BXSLIDER;
```